# IRFZ44N with Arduino works fine on breadboard but not when directly connected with wire

Tags: arduino, mosfet, photodiode, breadboard

I have a circuit that looks like this in the picture below.

[image]

I am getting 5V to power Arduino Nano BLE 33 from the powerboost 500 module that is connected to the 450mAh lipo battery and the wireless charger receiver. The photodiode module (veml7700 from adafruit) is being powered by the Arduino 3.3V. Also the laser is being controlled by Arduino pin D3 which is being connected to the IRFZ44N MOSFET with pull down resistor. The laser seems to have a constant current driver with working voltage from 3V to 4.5V although it is still working with 5V. I am also using Arduino Nano BLE 33 to have a Bluetooth connection to my phone to read and show the photodiode readings in real time. In order for me to get the readings, I am using the MOSFET to turn the laser on 1 sec before the photodiode reading and to turn off 1 sec after the photodiode reading.

Everything seems to work find when I test the circuit on the breadboard. However, the problem occurs when I try to put everything together by directly wiring them together.

The photodiode reading starts to fluctuate like the picture below.

[image]

There is no problem with the Bluetooth connection and the conversion of the data between the Arduino and the Android App. I know this because the app correctly converts the transmitted data from the Arduino. The problem is that the photodiode reading itself isn't consistent when directly connected with wires instead of using the breadboard.

I tried to troubleshoot and found out that the MOSFET is not completely shutting down fast enough but instead have a little voltage carrying over to the next cycle like the picture below.

[image]

To trouble shoot, I replaced the laser with LED and tested the MOSFET. It is shutting down and on perfectly like below.

[image]

I know that it is not the battery issue since when I was testing with breadboard, I also used the same battery to power all the circuit. Using the breadboard, it was working perfectly fine, so fluctuation in photodiode reading. I also checked every wiring to make sure that the grounds are all connected. They all seem to have a good connection.

I desperately need some help to figure out why my circuit doesn't work when directly wired instead of using the breadboard.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please draw a schematic diagram, instead of the cartoon wiring diagram ... you can use the included schematic editor ... use the `save and insert` button when the diagram is finished

Comment: You have an oscilloscope so why have you not measured the gate voltage and voltage drop on the drain wire? My guess is the  gate not being driven correctly.

Comment: I think you should check max current rating of nano 3.3V output with current draw from the laser pcb assembly. Also can you change the pulse current to allow for settling?

Comment: _"the MOSFET is not completely shutting down fast enough but instead have a little voltage carrying over to the next cycle like the picture below."_ - To me it looks like the FET is turning off (high Drain voltage) quickly, but taking a while to turn on fully (low Drain voltage). Please confirm if that is what the scope trace shows.